# How to get access to outlook mail in iOS via web services

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, outlook, hotmail

I'm trying to access to outlook mail headers and attachments, I have already implemented oAuth2 and i have login and access token. I tried to access mail via imap but it is incredibly slow so I'm looking for another option. Is web calls the answer or do you have another option

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Exchange Web Services API (it is HTTP based) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer! i look into the documentation but i still have no idea where are the endpoints that i need to hit. Can you help ?

Comment: The endpoints are extracted from autodiscover baased on the user's SMTP address: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124251(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: You can test autodiscover from https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/. That will give you the end points. You can also test from Outlook: Ctrl + right click the Outlook icon in the tray area and select "Test Email AutoConfigutation".

Comment: I'm sorry to say that i haven't found a way to know the API endpoints to get email from outlook/hotmail :(